# how to convert a string into an array of characters - java 8

Tags: java, arrays, string

**Passed in string:** hello

**populate arrayA[] with:** ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];

Without using any packages or imports

```
    int size = a.length();
    
    String arrayA[] = new String[size];
    
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    //pass each index in the string to arrayA
    }
```

Comment: Do you want an array of characters or an array of single-character strings?  Your title and your partial code are contradictory.

Comment: Either `String[] arrayA = a.split("")` or `char[] chars = a.toCharArray()` - depending on what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could be solved using `String#split`.

```
String[] lettersOfHello = "hello".split("");
```

Will need to circle back if it is preinstalled in Java 8 or no introduced until a later package.

Comment: *Will need to circle back if it is preinstalled in Java 8* - what do you mean?

Comment: What is "`foo`"?

Comment: probably a placeholder variable for whatever string to be passed in @Kaan

Comment: Answers should be clear about what they're doing (and why).

Comment: Fails with most characters. Try using `"AB"`, resulting in `[A, B, ?, ?]`. See this happen [live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/BDKpKr). To work with individual characters, use code point integer numbers, not `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that:

- doesn't use any imports – *except* for `java.util.Arrays` so that it can print out the character array for verification, but that's only for this answer, doesn't have anything to do with the code solution itself.
- builds an array of Character, and not `java.lang.String` as you posted in your code – your expected output `["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]` could be an array of Strings (double-quotes) but also looks like it would work as characters

```
import java.util.Arrays;

String s = "hello";
Character[] chars = new Character[s.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    chars[i] = s.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println("chars[]: " + Arrays.toString(chars));
```

Here's the output:

```
chars[]: [h, e, l, l, o]
```

Comment: `char` is a legacy type. Fails with most characters, those found outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Use code point integer numbers for widest compatibility.

Comment: Great point. Updated the example to replace `char` with `Character`.

Comment: `Character` is just a wrapper class around the `char` primitive type. Like `Float` for `float`. So like `char`, `Character` is also legacy, and also fails with most characters. Learn to use code point integer numbers instead. See the `codePoint` methods found on classes `String`, `StringBuilder`, `Character`, etc. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72907680/642706).

Comment: Interesting.. I've rarely done anything directly with individual character data, thanks for the comments+info. Looking more closely at [java.lang.Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), this solution as posted will handle unicode characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF, and probably do broken things with unicode characters beyond that.

Comment: Yes, correct. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically able to handle only the first 65,536 code points, the [Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). That covers less than half of the 144,697 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5 when the code point methods were added.

Answer (score -1):

## tl;dr

The `char` type is legacy, essentially broken, and fails with most characters. See `char` fail in [live code at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/BDKpKr). See my Comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72905619/how-to-convert-a-string-into-an-array-of-characters-java-8/72907680#comment128785610_72905727) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72905619/how-to-convert-a-string-into-an-array-of-characters-java-8/72907680#comment128785405_72906203) on this page.

Use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers when working with individual characters.

```
"hello"
.codePoints()
.mapToObj( Character :: toString )
.toArray( String[]::new )
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Lbnkan).

> [h, e, l, l, o, ]

## Code points

A code point is the number assigned permanently to each character identified by Unicode.

```
int[] codePoints = "hello".codePoints().toArray() ;
```

> [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]

Get the character for each of those code points.

```
List< String > lettersOfHello = 
    Arrays
    .stream( codePoints )
    .mapToObj( Character :: toString )
    .toList() 
;
```

See this code [run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/VziN01).

> [h, e, l, l, o]

Answer (score -2):

This can be done using [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()).

```java
String foo = "example";

char[] fooChars = foo.toCharArray();
```

If you actually want a string array for each character you can simply use `.toString()`.

```java
String[] fooChars = new String[foo.length()];
    
for(int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++){
    fooChars[i] = foo.charAt(i).toString();
}
```

Comment: `error: char cannot be dereferenced` inside the for loop

Comment: `fooChars[i] = String.valueOf(foo.charAt(i));` is the correct syntax